# How can I pass and update a (environment) variable into my project on each compile with webpack?

Tags: javascript, variables, webpack, hook

I'm working on a webpack workflow where each time I change something to my project code an automatic commit is made. I want to pass the commit hash inside the compiled bundle so I can reference the hash inside the project (it's for version control / export purposes).

The automatic commit is done via a webpack hook but I can't figure out how to pass the commit hash to the bundle. For the passing of the hash I've looked at DefinePlugin but this - to me - only seems to work on runtime. Could you update a DefinePlugin variable on each compile?

Hope somebody could help or point me into the right direction!